# How do change the value of a session before form submission

Tags: forms, sessions

I created a custom module that allows users to enter their information, and during the form submission, I set a session with the name that they type in the form:

```
$session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
$session->remove('contact_first_name');
$session->set('contact_first_name', $form_state->getValue('first_name'));
```

Next, I set the name as a variable to be used on another page that I created as a thank you.

mytheme.theme:

```
function scottishleader_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $variables['signupname'] = \Drupal::request()->getSession()->get('contact_first_name');
}
```

Inside a template, I am now able to use the "signupname" as a variable.

But now I noticed that if the user goes back to the form and enters different detail, after the submission, the signupname" variable still return the name of the previous session.

**Question:** How can I delete or empty this specific session before the form gets submitted?

**NOTE:** I cannot destroy all the sessions because there is a session that must always be kept alive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I destroy or unset session?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229018/how-can-i-destroy-or-unset-session)

Comment: @NoSssweat the question is not exactly a duplicate because the answer does not work for me.

Comment: It's due to caching. Not session related.

Comment: Yes, try to display the session variable in a block with a cache context: `$build['#cache']['contexts'] = ['session'];`